# Return largest subset or value of number from list that equals to x

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization, subset-sum

I'm trying to return the largest numbers that make up the sum of a value given and if there's one number that makes up that value from the list return that instead

```
numberlist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,16,32,64,128]

def getSubsetOrSingle(x,listofvalues):
    if x in listofvalues:
        return x
    else:
        return list()# list of the biggest values available that make up x
```

I'm able to match the value of x in the list such as if you were to pass

```
getSubsetOrSingle(128, numberlist)
```

it will return you 128 but I I would like to pass 208 and get back the biggest possible values that amount to it from the list as so:

```
>>> print(getSubsetOrSingle(208, numberlist))
>>> [16,64,128]
>>> print(getSubsetOrSingle(128, numberlist))
>>> 128
>>> print(getSubsetOrSingle(33, numberlist))
>>> [1,32]
>>> print(getSubsetOrSingle(136, numberlist))
>>> [8,128]
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt of getting the possible values

Comment: if the list is always '0,1,2,4,8,..,128'  you could make 'x'  a binary number... Check the binary number for 1's, and you will get your 'numberlist'

Comment: Hey @GijsDenHollander It's actually not a binary number list but just a data set that's looks like one

Comment: @yklsga I'm working on it, I've attempted with using the max() function and popping off the largest element in the list and looping through it again but no luck as it would only compare the largest elements and not the smaller elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d handle this problem by splitting it into two cases. The case where you check for whether the target number is exactly equal to any of the elements in the input list is probably pretty easy to implement. The other case you’re looking at can be solved by a nice dynamic programming / memoization approach.

Let’s start with a slow recursive algorithm that we can then convert into a DP style recurrence. Imagine that you want to solve the following problem:

> What is the maximum quantity of numbers you can use to sum up to some target number T using only the first k numbers from the list?

As a base case, if k = 0 (that is, you get to work with zero numbers), then you can make T = 0 using zero numbers and it’s impossible to make T > 0 in any ways. We’ll denote this by saying that you need -&infinity; numbers to do this to signify that it’s not possible.

Now, suppose you have k > 0 numbers to work with. In that case, you have two options. One option would be to include the kth number as part of the total. If that number is m, then you’d then want to form T - m using the first k - 1 numbers using as many numbers as possible. (You can only do this if m ≤ T.) The other option is to not include the kth number, in which case you’d want to form T using as many coins as possible from the first k - 1 coins.

Here’s some rough pseudocode for this. I’m assuming that adding anything to negative infinity gives back negative infinity:

```
function mostNumbersFor(numberList, k, T) {
    /* Base case: if T < 0, we can’t make T. */
    if (T < 0) return -infinity;

    /* Base case: if k = 0, we can only make T = 0. */
    if (k == 0) {
        return T == 0? 0 : -infinity;
    }

    /* Otherwise, we either include the current number, or we don’t.
     * We take the better of the two options.
     */
    return max(mostNumbersFor(numberList, k - 1, T),
               mostNumbersFor(numberList, k - 1, T - numberList[k - 1]) + 1);
}
```

If you then call

```
mostNumbersFor(numberList, numberList.length + 1, T);
```

you’ll get the maximum quantity of numbers that add up to exactly T.

Now, this approach is really, really slow because it’ll make all sorts of duplicated recursive calls. However, if you add in memoization or dynamic programming to eliminate those redundant calls, this gets a lot faster. Specifically, there are only O(n) possible values for k (where n is the length of the input list) and only O(W) possible values for the T parameter, where W is the input target value. That makes the overall runtime O(nW), which is pseudopolynomial in W and probably very fast in practice for small values of W.